# How to find 2d angles for 3d vectors?

Tags: vectors, triangles, angle

I have three vectors in 3d that originate at a point. If I look at them along a line perpendicular to a plane that intersects two of them, how do I find the angles between those two vectors and the third one?

Clarification because this is frickin difficult to explain:

[image]

I'll also accept a way to find how much of the longest line is on either side of the shorter line, because that's ultimately what I need.

Comment: What is the *angle between those two vectors and the third one*? I know the angle between two vectors but not the kind of angle you ask for. Or do you mean the angle between the plane (defined by two vectors) and another vector? Please update your question to precise that point.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. I'll suggest you delete the first paragraph and expand the last, using well-labelled figures, since that's ultimately what you want. There might be a better way to get at it than you think.

Comment: For example, do you mean given three vectors $a,b,c$ how do you find the angle between the plane determined by $a,b,$ and the vector $c$? If that's it, then you want to take the dot product of $a×b$ and $c$ in two ways. That is, form the equation $|a×b||c|\cos\phi=(a×b)\cdot c,$ where $\phi$ is the angle between a normal to the plane of $a,c,$ and the vector $c.$ Then the angle you want is $90°-\phi.$ I really don't understand your last paragraph. As I said, it's better to expand on that and clarify.

Comment: Is the “shorter line” the projection of the third vector onto the plane spanned by $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Hi the dot product ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)) is a great way to do that

here is a random [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDdR5s0C4cY&t=)

it seems I need to develop here a bit further sorry about the links I just wanna help^^

lets $\vec{OA}=\vec{A},\vec{OB}=\vec{B},\vec{OC}=\vec{C}$ be three vectors in 3D.

In the **special case** where $\vec{A}$ is **perpendicular** to $\vec{B}$ you can project $\vec{C}$ into the plane define by the two vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ as the following sum

"**the projection of $\vec{C}$ on $\vec{A}$**" + "**the projection of $\vec{C}$ on $\vec{B}$**"

so $\vec{C_{proj}} =(\frac{\vec{C}\cdotp\vec{A}}{\vec{A}\cdotp\vec{A}}\vec{A}+\frac{\vec{C}\cdotp\vec{B}}{\vec{B}\cdotp\vec{B}}\vec{B}) $

next you can find the angle between $\vec{C_{proj}}$ and $\vec{A}$ with the formule from the dot product:

$\theta=\arccos (\frac{\vec{C_{proj}}\cdotp\vec{A}}{\|\vec{C_{proj}}\|\|\vec{A}\|})$

**EDITED for the case where $\vec{A}$ is not perpendicular to $\vec{B}$**

**the general case**: $\vec{C_{proj}} = \vec{C}-\frac{\vec{C}\cdotp(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})}{(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\cdotp(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})}(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})$

note:

$(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})$ is call the **cross product** of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$

$(\vec{A}\cdotp\vec{B})$ is call the **dot product** of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$

ps: don't forget there is always two possibles answers for the angle between two vectors $\theta$ and $(360-\theta)$ and think about rad or degrees

**ANOTHER SOLUTION:**

using @amd resoning you can find another formula for your end goal:

Let $\vec{N}=(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})\times\vec{C}$

then $\frac{\vec{A}\cdotp\vec{N}}{\vec{A}\cdotp\vec{N}+\vec{B}\cdotp\vec{N}}\|\vec{A}-\vec{B}\|$ and $\frac{\vec{B}\cdotp\vec{N}}{\vec{A}\cdotp\vec{N}+\vec{B}\cdotp\vec{N}}\|\vec{A}-\vec{B}\|$ are how much of the longest line is on either side of the shorter line.

you can interpret "the direction of $\vec{C_{proj}}$" as "the vertical black vector", $\vec{N}$ as X , the fraction in front as the ratio between one of the rectangle(green or red) divide by both combine while $\|\vec{A}-\vec{B}\|$ is the lenght of the "longest line" as you call it.[image]

cheers

Comment: Your answer as of now is basically a link-only answer. Please put some of the information in the question as links can change.

Comment: I just edited sorry about that ^^

Comment: Your formula for the projection of $C$ onto the span of $A$ and $B$ is only valid if $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal. All we know from the question, though, is that they’re linearly independent.

Comment: How are you multiplying the vectors? We've only started vectors in class and we were told that you can only multiply vectors by scalars

Comment: @amd you are right,my mistake, I edited again hehe!  Gridzbi Spudvetch you have the "dot product" and the "cross product" between vectors , if you did not see this in class it is ok look around you will get there in no time.

Answer (score 0):

$cos\phi = \frac{\vec v \bullet \vec u}{|\vec v|*|\vec u|}$

You also might need to project the vectors on the same plane, and than use the formulare, if you are referring to the vectors having a "2D angle" as having a certain angle when projected onto a shared plane.

Comment: Yes! thank you, that's what I meant: the angles between the vectors when vector C is projected onto the plane formed by vectors A and B.

Comment: Ok, so you need to project the vector C onto the A,B plane and afterwards the formulare I wrote should be sufficient! Obtaining the length of the two segments of the line you were looking for can be acquired by getting one of the angles and then using the length of the projected vector C and the vector A or B which build the angle with C and using the cosine rule! This will give you the first segment, now you can repeat the process for the second segment!

Comment: *half of the length of projected vector C :D

Answer (score 0):

I’m glad that you mentioned the problem that you’re ultimately trying to solve because that can be worked out directly from the three vectors without resorting to computing angles or projections. Essentially, you need to find the intersection point of the line through points $A$ and $B$ with the line defined by the projection of the third vector $C$ onto the plane $P$ spanned by $A$ and $B$. This is equivalent to computing the intersection of the line $AB$ (the extension of the longer diagonal in your illustration) with the plane perpendicular to $P$ that contains $C$.

So, let $N = (A\times B)\times C$. $A\times B$ is perpendicular to the plane $P$, and $N$ is perpendicular to both this and $C$, so it is normal to the plane with which we want to intersect the line. Every point on this plane satisfies the equation $N\cdot X=0$. Expressing the line $AB$ as $Q(t) = (1-t)A+tB$, we then solve $$N\cdot Q(t) = N\cdot\left((1-t)A+tB\right) = 0,$$ so $$t = {N\cdot A\over N\cdot A-N\cdot B}.\tag1$$ As long as the projection of $C$ lies between $A$ and $B$ as you’ve pictured, the denominator won’t vanish.

Now, this parameterization has the property that $t$ is equal to ${\lvert QA\rvert\over\lvert BA\rvert}$, so it gives you the proportion of the segment $AB$ that lies on the “$A$ side” of the intersection. If you want the actual distance, you need only multiply $t$ by the distance between $A$ and $B$.

This result makes geometric sense: For any point $X$, $N\cdot X$ is proportional to its distance from the plane defined by $N$; the sign tells you which side of the plane the point is on. So, formula (1) says that the distance to the intersection along the segment $AB$ is in proportion to the perpendicular distances to $P$, which can be demonstrated with similar triangles.